# How can I get and use a user's TZ setting from their .bashrc in a Perl CGI script?

Tags: bash, perl, timezone

Each of my users has a (possibly) different TZ defined in their *.bashrc*.  I have a Perl script that displays date/time and want it to have it display with their profile time zone.

Does anyone know the best way to do this?

Comment: How is the Perl script being run?

Comment: How would the webserver know what user is querying it?

Comment: That CGI information is just the sort of thing you should put in the question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple answer is to use:

```
    use POSIX;
    .... 
    print strftime("%H:%M %Z", localtime);
```

But the zone returned by %Z varies from system to system. I have got `GMT Daylight Time` and `BST` on two different platforms.

**Edit** 
The following is an experiment showing that (at least for me) %Z takes account of TZ

```
    export TZ=''
    perl -MPOSIX -e 'print strftime("%H:%M %Z\n", localtime)'
    export TZ=America/Los_Angeles
    perl -MPOSIX -e 'print strftime("%H:%M %Z\n", localtime)'
```

Produces output

```
    16:45 UTC
    09:45 PDT
```

Comment: %Z returns the server timezone.  I am looking for a way to return the TZ set in the user's /.bashrc or /.bash_profile.  Do you know of a way to do that?  Sorry if my original message was unclear.

Comment: It returns the users timezone for me (debian).  What odes the script above give for you.

Comment: Same output as you...
so I am getting closer...
If I put this into my perl script: $ENV{'TZ'}="America/Los Angeles"; it returns the correct TZ.

Now, my perl script will run for any user, and I know the value of $CURRENT_USER which corresponds to /home/<user>/... how can I pull out that user's TZ variable from basrc or bash_profile?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the wonderful module [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) for this:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use DateTime;

# extract timezone name from file in env variable
(my $tz = $ENV{TZ}) =~ s#^/usr/share/zoneinfo/##;
my $now = DateTime->now(time_zone => $tz);

print "The current time is: " . $now->strftime('%F %T %Z') . "\n";
```

When I run this with TZ="/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris", I see:

> The current time is: 2010-04-19 20:09:03 CEST

As for extracting the timezone data from the user's file: a quick solution is to store that user's TZ configuration in a separate file (which .bashrc could source), and you can parse it manually in the CGI (however this gets into a different topic: How can I best store per-user configurations for a CGI?)

```
# /home/<user>/.tz should have the content: export TZ="/usr/share/zoneinfo/timezonename"
open(my $tz_fh, "/home/${user}/.tz");
chomp(my $tz_data = <$tz_fh>);
close $tz_fh;
(my $tz_path) = $tz_data =~ m/^export TZ\s*=\s*"(.+)"$/;

# now $tz_path contains what $ENV{TZ} would contain in the earlier code snippet.
```

Comment: Cool -- and it runs on mine machien too... the question is how can it dynamically read from a user's profile?  If the script is running under the "apache" user, and it grabs the $CURRENT_USER, how can I tell the script to pull the CURRENT_USER's environment variable?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood -- I thought it was running under the user's environment, in which case the user's .bashrc would already be loaded.  In that case, the best thing might be to store that user's TZ configuration in a separate file (which .bashrc could source), and you can parse manually in the CGI: I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Whats a "profile" in this context?

Comment: In /home/<user>/.bashrc I have the following line:
export TZ="/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris"

Another user @ /home/<user2>/.bashrc has:
export TZ="/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London"

I'd like my perl script to use that TZ for its display.